# Vim: Concatenate 2 columns of text horizontally

Tags: vim

Say I have a file

```
a
b
c
```

And in another I have

```
1
2
3
```

Can I, in Vim (or in shell in general), somehow copy the second one into the first one to get

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the below step by step approach in vim, to achieve the same.

1. Open the first file containing
   a
   b
   c
2. Open the second file containing
   1
   2
   3
3. In the second file, go to vertical select, by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> (vertical select mode) for windows gVim, if in other OS, go for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> (vertical select mode). once all the lines are selected, press <kbd>y</kbd> to yank the content.
4. Go to first file and go to line 1 after a and type <kbd>p</kbd> to paste the content. you will get the content as desired by you.

Comment: Ho well. So simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

use this on shell:

```
paste file1 file2 | sed 's/\t/ /' >> outputfile
```

If you remove the sed part the output file will have tab separated values.

Comment: No need for `sed`: `paste -d' ' file1 file2` will have the columns separated by space.

Comment: Ho didn't know about that. Even better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
vi file2 file1
```

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

select all the column with arrow down, then hit <kbd>y</kbd> in *command mode*, then `:n` in *command mode*.

In the second file, line 1, add two space in *edit mode*, then hit <kbd>p</kbd> in *command mode*